# An easy way to linux, please

Tags: windows-7

I installed ubuntu three times in the hard drive of my PC, but windows7 don't recognized it. How can I have dual boot order, in an easy maner?. I saw some video tutorials, but they are a little complicated. Please help me. I really want to try linux.

Comment: When installing, you need to select device for boot loader installation. Did you select entire disk (dev/sda), not Ubuntu partition (for example dev/sda1)?

Answer (score 0):

If you install Ubuntu first and then Windows , the Windows is going to overwrite the MBR and create bunch of errors.
Provided that your Windows is healthy

1. Burn Ubuntu Live USB / DVD (You can do it via Unetbootin).
2. Boot the machine in Live Ubuntu environment.
3. Open up terminal and type

   `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair; \`

   `sudo apt-get update; \`

   `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`
4. Once the boot-repair window pops up , click on recommended repair.
5. Reboot.
   This might do the trick

Comment: Might be a good idea to mention that he has to run Ubuntu from the burned disc and perform the repair within that Ubuntu environment

Comment: @danielbockersorensen I've edited the ans :-)

Comment: Actually  the problem is probaly in the BIOS, you need to select which OS to boot in the BIOS. See -http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Comment: What if his was not MBR? Will the same apply for GPT tables?

Comment: @user3073656 - READ THE LINK I GAVE  -"TROUBLESHOOTING

YOUR COMPUTER BOOTS DIRECTLY TO WINDOWS

This is a common problem and if you do not get a GRUB menu , re-installing or repairing grub will NOT HELP"

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I see, but then it is not there in my BIOS! See [this](http://i.imgur.com/wfVxFgq.jpg) screenshot!

Comment: @user3073656 - You have to look through the uefi menu or if you can not find it contact the vendor